# iOS- How to paint in the within limits

Tags: ios, opengl-es, draw, paint

I used the scanning line seed filling algorithm to realize the color filling function.

But I don't know how to do that. When my pen lands in the flower, I need to draw only Inside the black edge of the flower,do not draw in the hair.

I have tried to use :

   `CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
   layer.contents = (__bridge id)(image.CGImage);
    self.drawView.layer.mask = layer;`

But the plan didn't work.
if any one gives solution it would be so great,Thank you.
(English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.)
[image]

Comment: There is a similar question: [How to draw inside the black edges in iOS SDK with OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944736/how-to-draw-inside-the-black-edges-in-ios-sdk-with-opengl-es)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a two pass approach.

- Use the same algorithm as the fill algorithm to create a stencil mask which fills the area you want to allow the pen to draw.
- Draw the pen with stencil testing to constrain it to the allowed region.

Similar approach could be used to create an alpha-mask on the fly (e.g. as a texture), and mix that with the pen drawing.

Comment: @solidpixel, i am also facing same issues, i want to draw inside the line, i have done  context?.setBlendMode(.sourceIn) with this, but it took too m ch time to drawing.