# How to make UIImage background color transparent

Tags: xcode, uiimage, uicolor

I need to change any background color of UIImage to transparent color. I am able to change white color to transparent color, but i need to change any color to transparent not any particular color.

Comment: please explain your question further.

Comment: i need to pick image from gallery and make its background transparent.

Comment: okay & how do you do the existing operation for white background ? code snippet would be enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443311/how-to-make-one-colour-transparent-in-uiimage

Comment: Done this, by picking color on tap and remove that particular color